# AR Portal attached to real-life wooden frame

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying build a AR app using Vuforia. The app will be part of an art installation. The idea is that the app should recognize a wooden frame and display a portal to another world inside of it. See the following sketch for clarification:
[image: sketch]

I am wondering what would be the best approach to detect this frame. Because this is an art installation, we'd like to keep things as sober as possible. So preferable no large images. A pattern on the frontside of the frame could be an option, but I'm afraid this will make the art-work look less beautiful.
Maybe through object detection using a CAD drawing of the frame (but it's a very simple U-shape without a lot of features)?
Another option could be to place markers on the floor.
**Or, is it possible to have a combination of images, objects, ground plane, markers, all working together provide steady tracking? How would that work?**

What is important is that we have a high quality tracking, with as little flickering or drift as possible. And this during the entire time the user is exploring the virtual world.

Any ideas on how to best approach this?

So far, for testing, I've been using a large image placed on top of the frame, but in the art-installation this will not be possible.

Comment: Have you considered area targets? Is this feasible in your situation?

Comment: I'm guessing this not possible, as the art-installation will be exposed in different venues.

Comment: I mean you could create area targets for each venue, that seems like a reasonable amount of effort. Another idea would be to have an image target next to some explanation text. Usually, art installations have a sign with some explanatory text in front/close by. Maybe, you could place a marker on the sign which then in turn activates the AR frame?

Comment: These venues will be world wide. The cost of sending a developer to each venue to do a scan is too high. The marker on a sign could be a good idea though. But this will require exact placing of the sign in 3D space so that it aligns with the frame. The more I think of it, the more I am in favor of some small markers on the frame a few big ones on the floor. Detailed plan with measurements should help the people doing the build-up to place the markers in the exact positions. But I'm still not sure on how to combine all of those targets to determine the best position of my 3D model...